# Magento 2 Image issues

Tags: product-images, image, media-images

I've been having an issue with getting the product images to load properly.

I migrated the site from M1 to M2 and brought over all of the media files per the recommended methods. Some of the product images are loading, but the vast majority are just using the placeholder image.

I have tried to run php bin/magento catalog:image:resize but it terminates after ~10min or so (never in the same spot) and always starts back at the beginning if I run it again. I have talked with the hosting company (bluehost) and they said this:

> I have checked the command that you are running and also tried
>   executing the command which gets terminated. Since you are on a shared
>   hosting account, we have limitations on the shared server.
>   Unfortunately the command times out after a certain time. So you would
>   need to make a batch of these images and then execute it.  Instead of
>   running the complete 8680, please make batches of 500 images and then
>   execute the command one by one.

So, is there a way to get the image resize process to use batches? I couldn't find any documentation on this.

What alternatives might I have to get the product images working?

Thanks.

Comment: I also tried implementing the fix [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b065cd3e7201c1f7b0b45efe29020662d15ad9f1) but it's still just showing the placeholder.
I also tried deleting the placeholder, but now it just shows the default M2 placeholder image.

Comment: Only the main product image isn't loading, when I look at the source it's pointing to a directory that doesn't exist pub/media/catalog/product/cache/c248ea6a06e53ed0310446822e5ac87f/p/r/product_image.jpg

If I manually create this directory and add images, the images will appear on the front end...